# Python and background running program with 'shortcut keys'

Tags: python

I'm looking for a way to allow a program to run in the background while during other tasks, and still be able execute commands by input from the user, in the form a short-cut keys.

For example: if I'm browsing a homepage and press shift-f a method will execute in a background running python program.

Comment: you need to set a hook on the global event queue. try a library - here is one that [sounds promising](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/). Note I didn't try this

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Xlib.display`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) to capture keyboard input even when your application is not in focus.

Here is a very basic example:

```
from Xlib.display import Display
from pprint import pprint
import time

disp = Display()

while 1:
    time.sleep(0.06) # This is the lowest value that ensures Xlib won't recognize a single keypress twice
    keymap = disp.query_keymap()
    pprint(keymap)
```

This will print the values captured to the CLI, even if the terminal running the application does not have focus.

Comment: That will give me a ImportError: No module named 'fcntl'
Is this a question for another topic.

Comment: @vandelay: Yes, that is an entirely different issue.